# Accessing a json object with an unknown key in Rust. Is there an easier way?

Tags: rust, hashmap

Recently I've started on a rust project of mine that interacts with a API that serves json back. And I need to access a value that has been named as a ID which I have no way of predicting. A HashMap was offered as a solution, and it does work, but it isn't the prettiest way of doing it and clippy is complaining of a loop that never loops.

```
let deserialized : HashMap<String, Value> = serde_json::from_str(&filtered_string).unwrap();

let mut deserialised_filter : String = "".to_string();

for (_, value) in deserialized {
    deserialised_filter = value.to_string();
    break
};
```

So is this completely the wrong way of doing it or is there no way of accessing it easier?

Comment: You could just get first of the [`values`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.values), without the loop.

Comment: Okay so there is a way, that's good to know, but so far I haven't been able to find it myself. From what I gathered all the functions relating to a HashMap would require me to know the name of the key, or they return an iterator, which leads pretty much back to the loop (as far as I've used iterators that is).

Comment: something like `let value = deserialized.values().nth(0)`. (`nth` returns you an `Option<Value>`, you should handle the case of `None`)

Comment: Seems that will work, thanks for the help.

Comment: your algo don't make sense, order in hashmap is random everytime you iter it

Comment: Yes I do recognise that the order of the hashmap will be random, but it'll only ever have a single item in it so it also has to be the first one. My only problem with accessing that item is not knowing the name of it.